# How to run a specific test case from a suite in jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have 120 test cases and I execute all these test cases through a pom.xml (maven) file in jenkins.

Now if I want to execute just one of these 120 test cases, how can I do that?
Is there any way to give the inputs to jenkins while in run-time?

If anyone has an idea on how to do that please share.

Answer (score 1):

I am new here, I cannot comment. I am assuming you are using maven surefire plugin, If so you can pass in any particular test name in maven goal

```
mvn -Dtest={your-test} test
```

If not, you can edit question with some details/may be part of pom.xml and maven goal from jenkins.

Comment: Good answer. Actually OP can modify goal of existing Jenkins job or create a copy of existin job with modified goal. There was also an option to define job with parameters, so when you click "Build with parameters" you can either choose a default goal or enter the goal with reuired test name.

Comment: Thanks for valuable answer @DevOps_101 ,  I have followed your steps but I am getting the following error




[JENKINS] Recording test results
hudson.AbortException: Test reports were found but none of them are new. Did tests run? 
For example, C:\Users\hb\workspace\MFA\MFA\target\surefire-reports\TEST-TestSuite.xml is 56 min old

Comment: can you try to keep 5 tests in a independent project and run them once they all run, try this parameter to see if you can run 1 test to make sure we are trying to solve the problem in the right place also what jerkins version you are using on windows ?

Comment: Thanks once again for your help . Now I can able to run the scripts but I am using the parameter annotation for before method so it is throwing an error 

org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'folderName' is required by Configuration  annotation on method setUp_HerveLeger but has not been marked @Optional or defined

Comment: I am using jenkins version 1.596 v